# How to create a dynamic slider using php,my-sql,j-query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin, jquery-ui-slider

I was planing to create a website.It contains some dynamic contents.Which is a slider like [this](http://demo.kodspider.com) but now it is hard coded. I want to make it dynamic means using a my-sql db the slider should load images from a folder.And using some php script it should update the db with the new images from the folder, at each loading of website how do i do this please anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do the `lazy load` of data (load your data(**images**) on `scrolling` or `sliding`)

You could see a simple example [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html)

The example shown is for loading contents(not images) from the mysql database, but you could use the same logic loading dynamic images as well.

Comment: But where they wrote that data? they just wrote it inside the table.Here i need to obtain the path from the table the image is actually stored in the folder.